# Can I reuse my nameservers from one domain registrar with another?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, top-level-domains

My regular domain is one I got from GoDaddy.

Just recently, I registered a short .cr domain (Costa Rica) in http://www.nic.cr/ . During registration, they asked for nameservers (and just nameservers), so I thought of reusing my GoDaddy nameservers.

I kinda thought it would just be a straight-forward mapping, but nothing's happening, though. What am I missing here?

(There is an option to use their own nameservers, but I just wanted to explore this option. If there's nothing to be had here, I'll fall back to using theirs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jacob Hume's answer, I tried searching GoDaddy's Help section for "DNS Zone".

I eventually found the right help page, [Managing Domains with Off-Site DNS](http://community.godaddy.com/help/article/4041)

This does not require subscribing to their "Premium DNS" service, meaning this can be done without any extra charge.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to get GoDaddy to create a [DNS Zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone) for your domain, nic.cr, which they may charge a fee for. Check into their "[Premium DNS](http://www.godaddy.com/domains/dns-hosting.aspx?ci=42422)" service.

When you buy a domain from GoDaddy, and use their nameservers, their system automatically creates you a DNS Zone for that domain. Since you didn't register the Costa Rican domain with GoDaddy, they don't have a zone for it, and therefore there isn't any place for the server to add or retrieve records.

Hosting it with the registrar would be the path of least resistance, unless you find problems with their lookup speeds or some other issue.

Comment: Thanks for the lead.  I searched GoDaddy's Help section for "DNS Zone" and it led me to "Managing Domains with Off-Site DNS" http://community.godaddy.com/help/article/4041